# JavaScript vs PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Собственно сабж.
Ваше мнение? Возможен ли полный переход на JS(серверный)?)
Лично я уже начинаю немного переползать. Перспективно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы про Node.JS? 
Слышал про него и положительные и отрицательные отзывы, например, http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/nodejs/129640/. Он не соишком адекватно написан, но там приводятся цифры, что уже неплохо. Я бы предпочел python, например. Django для новичка немного сложнее, но зато избавляет от многих забот и ошибок.

Comment: вы ваабще вапрос читали?О_о?<br> Каким макаром тут python? Кстати для информации - от ошибок итзюавляет мозк и понимание языка а не python. не?

Comment: Во-первых, попрошу повежливее. Во-вторых, я счел, что systemiv спрашивал про серверную сторону JS. А еще мозг избавляет от грамматических ошибок тоже.

Comment: Да, читал этот пост. Автор не адекватен.
Ну насколько мне известно сейчас в яндексе на нём идёт разработка всех новых сервисов. И плсю то, что он разработан на движке от гугл. Не просто же так он его разработал. Достаточно крупные компании им заинтересовались.

Comment: Интерес не в статье, а в цифрах. А еще есть один минус: небольшой рынок хостинга => для любительски проектов он не очень-то подходит.

Comment: uramer, Вы правы. Он просто не знаком с серверным программированием на JS

Comment: http://www.heroku.com/ поддерживает серверный js.

Comment: Я бы не советовал полностью переходить на JS, т.к. если захочется освоить язык без событийных возможностей - придется переучиваться практически полностью. Пока что он вряд ли обгонит по производительности и функциональности прочие языки просто в силу недолгого развития.

Comment: Не очень понял суть сервиса, он, как я понимаю, позволяет запустить любое приложение? И еще и бесплатен?

P.s.:
Было бы интересно потестить производительность Node.js vs PHP vs Python.
нашел вот что; http://habrahabr.ru/company/ontico/blog/116211/

Comment: Да, но он вообще предназначен для Рубистов, но серверный JS тоже поддерживает.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос поставлен както неоднозначно... говорить о переходе, как по мне, можно было бы если бы JavaScript являлся бы серверным языком, а так лично мне не совсем понятна суть вопроса... По себе скажу - знаю и php и javascript, еще не было такого где бы я не писал серверный код... Вообще ели речь о ЗП чистого javascript программиста, то по статистике она выше чем у чистого php программиста, но это не означает что это так на самом деле, по опыту скажу - нормальных JavaScript программистов за всю жизнь практически не встречал, абсолютное большинство дяльше JQuery не видит...
Ну да не в этом суть, ИМХО пишите на обоих языках и позиционируйтесь как JavaScript, PHP разработчик...

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs

Comment: Я прошу прощения, перефразируйте както вопрос чтобы сразу было понятно что вы о Nodejs... <br>
Если так то ИМХО лучше оставаться на php, либо учить java(что будет намного сложнее, но почему java это круто думаю писать не стоит...)<br>
Хотя опять таки, хуже от знания еще одного "языка" вам не станет точно и если вам язык нравится ИМХО вопрос неактуален - вперед :)

Comment: Язык нравится тем, что у него не классическая модель, а завязанная на прототипах.  
Насчёт java, Вы знаете что под Android можно писать на связке html + + css + javascript (я имею ввиду именно приложения).  
Даже книжка где то продаётся

Comment: А причем тут android?..

Comment: Я думал Вы это имеете ввиду, когда говорили про JAVA

Comment: Вы бы почитали о Java И поняли бы сразу что Java это не только Android и это очень мягко говоря, к примеру сервер гугла когда был написан на плюсах, теперь же переписан и успешно функционирует на java...